# Roast tomato soup without broth/stock

Tags: soup, tomatoes

I am trying to make a vegetarian roast tomato and basil soup without using vegetable stock. A chef friend suggested making a mirepoix of vegetables, sweating them slowly, adding the roasted tomatoes and then water (instead of the stock).

My question is the amount of mirepoix I should use for 1kg tomatoes assuming my mirepoix is 2:1:1 onion, carrot and celery.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Why are you avoiding vegetable stock?

Comment: And a mirepoix + water is basically a vegetable stock? (Sans a few herbs and salt, but I suspect you will salt and spice the dish anyway.)

Comment: Thanks for the comments.

@Catija I would ideally like to avoid the extra step of having to make a veg stock and just make it all in one pot. I do not want to use a store bought stock.

Stephie Yes I realised this as i was writing the post so hopefully i get good results with the mirepoix and water approach !